# Is there a universal format/ method to locate configuration files in windows and linux?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In my application I have a configuration file(ABC.xml) in which we have the database attributes,log4j.xml path and others.The log4j.xml path is given in the ABC.xml as (`D:\log4j.xml`) and for linux as(`.\\..\\..\\log4j.xml\\`).

We are using apache tomcat server and we have the ABC.xml in the server context .

Is there any way ,such that I have the same representation of the path for log4j for both 
windows and linux  but it will be interpreted accordingly depending upon the server type?

Comment: tried using something called `classpath`?

Comment: @R.J: classpath is only useful for resources that the customer can't edit during the installation.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are using a servlet and the file is in the project, inside a servlet you can just:

```
InputStream is = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/log4j.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

java file handling can deal with `/` as seperator on windows operating systems too, so you can write in your ABC.xml `./../../log4j.xml` for both linux and windows (the path has to be relative and should not contain a drive letter).

So when you write in your code

```
File f = new File("./../../log4j.xml");
```

the argument `"./../../log4j.xml"` will for windows be translated internally to `".\\..\\..\\log4j.xml"` and

```
f.getAbsolutePath();
```

will return on windows the string `"C:\\some\\dir\\.\\..\\..\\log4j.xml"` witch prints as `C:\some\dir\.\..\..\log4j.xml` where `C:\some\dir` is the directory to witch `.\..\..\log4j.xml` is relative to.

Answer (score 1):

A common approach is to use paths relative to a system property. This allows you to specify the root folder in the OS specific format (`C:\...` or `/opt/`) and attach the relative part later.

Note that Java can handle Windows and Unix relative paths, so `new File( "C:\\app", "conf/log4j.xml" )` will actually try to open `C:\app\conf\log4j.xml`.

In your case, you could use this code:

```
File confFolder = new File( System.getProperty( "confDir" ) );
File log4j = new File( confFolder, "log4j.xml" );
```

Another option is to replace variable names in config files. That way you can have

```
<logConfDir>${appRoot}/conf</logConfDir>
<log4j>${logConfDir}/log4j.xml</log4j>
```

If there is a System property `logConfDir`, it should overwrite the config option. That will allow customers to do whatever they think necessary.

Comment: I have one more question.Is there a way such that I can place a configuration file(ABc.xml as mentioned in my question) in the server folder(eg.Tomcat folder) so that I can use the server path to load the configuration file and extract the contents using a xml parser eg.(SAX/DOM)? If there any such method to make my configuration file path to be server independent?

Comment: Yes: Put the location of the config file in a system property. That's the *only* way to make it server independent. For Tomcat, there would be other ways but they *only* work for Tomcat (i.e. **not** server independent)

Comment: Thank you ver much Aaron.Can you please tell me how to do this?...Please share me any tutorial links, so that I can have a much more clear idea on doing this

Comment: How to do what exactly? The code to read/use system properties is in my answer. To set system properties, use `CATALINA_OPTS` (http://www.springwebdevelopment.com/tomcat-more-memory-catalina_opts)